# Counting cells of worksheets within another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have one xlsm file with a single button in it which, when clicked, is supposed to open a separate workbook and search through all contained worksheets for cells of a specific colour.
The problem is, instead of searching the other workbook's worksheets, it just searches itself. I'm new to VBA, and feel like i've been round the internet 6 times trying to solve this. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim holdCount As Integer
Dim cellColour As Long
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range


Set wb = Workbooks.Open("blahblahblah.xls")
Set rng = Range("A1:A20")

holdCount = 0
cellColour = RGB(255, 153, 0)


For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.Color = cellColour Then
            holdCount = holdCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell
Next ws

MsgBox "found " & holdCount

End Sub
```

Comment: rng is not being reassigned in the loop. change `For Each cell in rng` to `for each cell in range(ws.cells(1,1),ws.cells(20,1))`

Comment: i tried that, but got an "application defined or object defined error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you aren't fully qualifying your `Range`

Move this inside of your ws loop instead of where it is now.

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A20")
```

Comment: i gave that a shot, and got "object doesn't support this property or method" spat back at me.

Comment: i've changed that, now i'm getting "object variable or with block variable not set". Should i be setting ws = [something] somewhere earlier on?

Comment: YES! Moving Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A20") inside the ws loop sorted it perfectly. Thank you so much; I could feel my hair falling out for a minute there.

Answer (score 0):

[BraX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422953/brax) pointed out that I needed to qualify the `Range` WITHIN the `For Each ws` loop, so here is the fixed and working code. Again, all credit to [Brax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422953/brax).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim holdCount As Integer
Dim cellColour As Long
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range


Set wb = Workbooks.Open("blahblahblah.xls")

holdCount = 0
cellColour = RGB(255, 153, 0)

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    With ws
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A20")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.Color = cellColour Then
            holdCount = holdCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    End With
Next ws

MsgBox "found " & holdCount
```

End Sub